# 'str' object has no attribute 'objects' django

Tags: django

My views.py file is

```
def studentFeedBack(request):
    studentid = ''
    courseid = ''
    teacherid = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':

        studentid_id = request.POST.get("studentid")
        studentid = studentid.objects.get(id=studentid_id)

        courseid_id = request.POST.get("courseid")
        courseid = courseid.objects.get(id=courseid_id)


        teacherid_id = request.POST.get("teacherid")
        teacherid = teacherid.objects.get(id=teacherid_id)




        description = request.POST.get("description")
        rating = request.POST.get("rating")
        
        studentFeedBack.objects.create(
            courseid=courseid,
            description=description, 
            studentid=studentid, 
            teacherid=teacherid, 
            rating=rating
        )


    return render(
            request,
            'forms/studentFeedBack.html',
            {
                
                'studentids':studentid.objects.all(),
                'courseids':courseid.objects.all(),
                'teacherids':teacherid.objects.all(),
                
            }
        )
```

and my models.py file is

```
class StudentFeedBack(models.Model):
    feedbackid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    courseid = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    submitdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    teacherid = models.ForeignKey('schoolTeacher', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    studentid = models.ForeignKey('Student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = [('Good','Good'),('Average','Average'),('Bad','Bad')]
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=option, default='none')   

                
class Course(models.Model):
    courseid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    coursedescription = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    coursename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    userid = models.IntegerField()
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    videolink = models.FileField(default='default_link')
    createddate = models.DateTimeField()
    imagelink = models.URLField(default='default_link')
    duration = models.DateTimeField()
    longdes = models.TextField()
    coursetype = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    assignto = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.BinaryField()

    def _str_(self):
        return self.coursename


    class Meta:
        db_table = "courseids"      


class schoolTeacher(models.Model):
    teacherid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    contact = models.IntegerField()
    passowrd = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg')
    regno = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    joiningdate = models.DateTimeField()

    def _str_(self):
        return self.name


    class Meta:
        db_table = "teacherids"    


class Student(models.Model):
    studentid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    regno = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    contactno = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    registrationdate = models.DateTimeField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    imagepath = models.ImageField(max_length=100, default='default.jpg')
    sectionid = models.IntegerField()

    def _str_(self):
        return self.name   


    class Meta:
        db_table = "studentids"
```

and studentFeedBack html file has the following form

```
<form action="/studentFeedBack/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
          
          <label for="studentid">Student Id</label>
          <!-- <input type="number" name="studentid"><br><br> -->
          <select name="studentid" required>
            {% for studentid in studentids  %}
              <option value="{{studentid.id}}">{{studentid.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
         </select><br><br>

          <!-- <label for="courseid">Course Id</label>
          <input type="number" name="courseid"><br><br> -->

          <label for="courseid">Course Id</label>
          <select name="courseid" required>
            {% for courseid in courseids  %}
              <option value="{{courseid.id}}">{{courseid.coursename}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
         </select><br><br>

          <label for="teacherid">Teacher Id</label>
          <!-- <input type="number" name="teacherid"><br><br> -->
          <select name="teacherid" required>
            {% for teacherid in teacherids  %}
              <option value="{{teacherid.id}}">{{teacherid.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
         </select><br><br>


          <label for="description" >Feedback</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description"></textarea><br><br>

          <label for="rating">Rating</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="Good" name="rating" value="Good">
          <label for="Good">Good</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="Average" name="rating" value="Average">
          <label for="Average">Average</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="Bad" name="rating" value="Bad">
          <label for="Bad">Bad</label><br><br>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

The studentFeedBack model has foreign keys from student, schoolTeacher and Course. This is giving error on browser that `'str' object has no attribute 'objects'`
Other than that my form is not giving any values in select options and that is also probably because of this error.

Comment: *"`studentid.objects`"* — You even named it *student id*. Of course just the *id* isn't the `Student` class.

Comment: I am a beginner to django hence its still the learning phase for me. I am unable to understand your reply.

Comment: You want something like `from .models import Student; ... Student.objects.get(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design of the view is the issue

According to the line

> studentid =''

studentid remains a string . You could try proper importation of the models.

Try:
views.py

```
from .models import Course, Student,schoolTeacher,studentFeedBack


def studentFeedBack(request):
    #studentid = ''
    #courseid = ''
    #teacherid = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        studentid_id = request.POST.get("studentid")
        studentid = Student.objects.get(id=studentid_id)

        courseid_id = request.POST.get("courseid")
        courseid = Course.objects.get(id=courseid_id)


        teacherid_id = request.POST.get("teacherid")
        teacherid = schoolTeacher.objects.get(id=teacherid_id)

        description = request.POST.get("description")
        rating = request.POST.get("rating")
        
        studentFeedBack.objects.create(
            courseid=courseid,
            description=description, 
            studentid=studentid, 
            teacherid=teacherid, 
            rating=rating
        )


    return render(
            request,
            'forms/studentFeedBack.html',
            {
                
                'studentids':Student.objects.all(),
                'courseids':Course.objects.all(),
                'teacherids':schoolTeacher.objects.all(),
                
            }
        )
```

Alternatively, Django is superb at handing forms for models
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

This will be better for your view as there is no validation at the moment

You could also have:

views.py

```
...
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory
from .models import studentFeedBack
def studentFeedBack(request):
    fields=[ 
    'courseid','description','studentid','teacherid','rating']
    form=modelform_factory(studentFeedBack, fields=fields)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=modelform_factory(studentFeedBack, fields=fields, data=request.POST)
        ## Validates the data submitted
        if form.is_valid():
            ## Creates a studentFeedBack instance
            form.save()
            ## If form is invalid, it will fall through to the template with the incorrect data. 
        else:
            ### Handle the incorrect form
            pass
    return render(
        request,
        'forms/studentFeedBack.html',
        {
            
            'studentids':Student.objects.all(),
            'courseids':Course.objects.all(),
            'teacherids':schoolTeacher.objects.all(),
            'form':form,
            
        }
    )
```

forms/studentFeedBack.html

```
<form action="/studentFeedBack/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    </form>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates

You may need to add a verbose_name attribute to your model fields:

models.py

```
class StudentFeedBack(models.Model):
    ...
    teacherid = models.ForeignKey('schoolTeacher', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Teacher")
    ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name

Customize as needed.

I hope this helps you understand Django better.

**Edit**

The function-based view has the same name as an imported model

For the first view:

```py
from .models import Course, Student,schoolTeacher
from .models import studentFeedBack as studentFeedBackModel


def studentFeedBack(request):
    #studentid = ''
    #courseid = ''
    #teacherid = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        studentid_id = request.POST.get("studentid")
        studentid = Student.objects.get(id=studentid_id)

        courseid_id = request.POST.get("courseid")
        courseid = Course.objects.get(id=courseid_id)


        teacherid_id = request.POST.get("teacherid")
        teacherid = schoolTeacher.objects.get(id=teacherid_id)

        description = request.POST.get("description")
        rating = request.POST.get("rating")
        
        studentFeedBackModel.objects.create(
            courseid=courseid,
            description=description, 
            studentid=studentid, 
            teacherid=teacherid, 
            rating=rating
        )


    return render(
            request,
            'forms/studentFeedBack.html',
            {
                
                'studentids':Student.objects.all(),
                'courseids':Course.objects.all(),
                'teacherids':schoolTeacher.objects.all(),
                
            }
        )
```

Comment: I tried the first view.py. It is giving the following error ```'function' object has no attribute 'objects'```

Comment: AttributeError at /studentFeedBack/
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: Exception Location: C:\Users\****\LG\forms\views.py, line 122, in studentFeedBack. It is giving error on this line in views.py ```'teacherids':schoolTeacher.objects.all()```

Comment: @AREEBAAKHTAR  I think the most recent edit solves the issue.

Comment: @AREEBA You may have a previous function called `schoolTeacher`

Comment: ```def schoolTeacher(request):
 return HttpResponse("Hello school teacher")```
thats all what i have for schoolTeacher in views.py

Comment: @AREEBA You rill need to rename(or remove ) the  `def schoolTeacher(request):  return HttpResponse("Hello school teacher") `view for the other  view to work. Also you may need to watch out for conflicting names in python